# I have two folders containing the same files (e.g. glfw,php5*,wget). Should I delete the other (non-Homebrew)?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Initially, I'm looking for a way to get the `phpMyAdmin mcrypt` working, and since I'm using Homebrew phpMyAdmin, I figured I must do something with Homebrew again.

When I used `brew doctor`, it reported that I have config scripts in `/usr/local/opt/php54/bin/php-config` that can confuse software installed via Homebrew.

I deleted the entire `php5*` folders (It was such a dumb moment for a beginner like me), and `brew doctor` reported a clear.

My Homebrew folder resides in `/usr/local/Cellar`. So I have almost identical folders residing in: `/usr/local/opt/` and `/usr/local/Cellar/`

I'm using the Cellar folder. Is it alright to delete all the files inside `/usr/local/opt/`? What preliminary actions should I do first to ensure no casualty?